# add class to accordion's div wrapper when all of the accordion's panes are collapsed (using Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an accordion effect implemented on my website using Twitter Bootstrap like so http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion.

Toggling the panels open and closed doesn't seem to add a class to any parent elements, only the .panel-headings and .panel-collapses...

I want it to add a class to the parent element (div.bs-example in the documentation's example) when all of the accordion's panels are closed/collapsed.

Does Bootstrap have an option for doing that?

If not, it seems like this would not be too hard to achieve...

- on clicking/collapsing an open `.panel-heading` add `class="all-closed"` to the parent element
- on clicking/opening an un-opened `.panel-heading` remove `"all-closed"` class (if it exists)

But maybe Bootstrap has an option for this?  Or maybe someone has some jQuery example to get me going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got some janky code to almost work... and just now discovered that I needed to use the `.on` method to make it truly work.

My solution looked like this:

```
$('.panel-group').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="collapse"]:not(".collapsed")', function() {
  $('.panel-group').addClass('allPanesClosed');
});
$('.panel-group').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed', function() {                     
  $('.panel-group').removeClass('allPanesClosed');
});
```